# The best way to optimize an API returning a large list of records in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint returning a list of 8000 records I have integrated it with an angular material application but the issue is that the list on the client-side is taking some time to load. Which options or suggestions can I utilize to optimize the loading of the records faster?

**view**

```
class PermitListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self,request,format=None):
        qs = IssuedPermit.objects.all()
        serializer = IssuedPermitSerializer(qs, many=True)
        # list_ = [json.loads(x.serialize_business()) for x in qs]

        return Response(data={"success": True, "msg": "success", "data":serializer.data})
```

Comment: If the issue is on the client side, then surely this question is more related to Angular than it is to Django? One solution on the Django side would be to use pagination so you are not dealing with such a large list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can't handle these many records at a time, since it will effect
>   the performance of application at the client end. 
> Alternatively,
>   you can just use pagination to handle request at the server end. This
>   will also ensure the performance boost up at the client side end. 
>   Moreover you have to integrate [pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) concept in django to
>   enable this feature.

Sending more records at a time will create load on the server as well as in the client end to handle these many records at a time. So better go with Pagination.

Sample code below :

#### Configuaration in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

#### Serializer:

```
class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1000
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10000

class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```